# Fluent Interface (Java) for object with getters and setters

Tags: java, fluent-interface

I read and enjoyed the article http://blog.jooq.org/2012/01/05/the-java-fluent-api-designer-crash-course/ from Lukas Eder and I would like to create a Fluent Interface for a class.

The class has four functions ("words" fill1 to fill4) that allow to set object attributes and four function ("words" get1 to get4) that get those attributes, but only if the required attributes have been set:

First I have to fill in the basic settings (fill1). After that I am either able to get some of those settings (get1 to get3) which are Strings. Or I am able to fill in some more information (fill2 to fill4). But only after *every* fill2 to fill4 has been invoked *at least once*, the final get4 can be invoked. How do I do this?

The first graph (states are the black dots) shows what I want to do, but as you can see the ? marks the part which is not clear, because if left as it is in the first graph, it would allow get4 to be called even if only one of fill2 to fill4 has been called.

The second graph would force that each fill2 to fill4 has been called but inforces the order and restricts that if I want to change e.g. fill3, I have to reset fill2 and fill4 as well.

The last graph would do what I want, but it has *13* states! Now if I imagine I would just add one more attribute to the group of fill2 to fill4, the number of states would explode even more.

[image]

**Edit:** Also, after thinking about it some more, I noticed that the way I'd do this (see below), would not even be able to implement the last graph, because after fill2 is invoked, we might be in different states - depending on what happened before.

What can / should I do?

**Edit:** I implement my fluent interfaces a little like a facade (if I got the design pattern right). What I mean: I leave the actual class nearly untouched - returning this (as in method chaining), however having the respective state interfaces as return values in the method signatures. The states are represented by nested interfaces. Example:

```
public class MyClass implements MyInterface.Empty, MyInterface.Full {

    String stuff;

    private MyClass(){};

    public static MyInterface.Empty manufactureNewInstance(){
        return new MyClass();
    }

    public MyInterface.Full fillStuff(String stuff){
        this.stuff = stuff;
        return this;
    }

    public String getStuff(){
        return stuff;
    }

}

public interface MyInterface {

    public interface Empty {
        public MyInterface.Full fillStuff();
    }

    public interface Full {
        public String getStuff();
    }

}

public class MyMain {

    pulic static void main(String[] args) {

        // For explaination:
        MyClass.Empty myclassEmpty = MyClass.manufactureNewInstance();
        MyClass.Full myclassFull = myclassEmpty.fillStuff("Hello World 1!");
        String result1 = myclassEmpty.getStuff();

        // As fluent chaining:
        String result2 = MyClass.manufactureNewInstance()
            .fillStuff("Hello World 2!")
            .getStuff();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Fluent interface APIs in Java are somewhat limited by the fact that you need to represent each *API state* by a different type. This is a consequence of Java types being the only way to communicate a set of API constraints to the Java compiler for validation.

Obviously, this is an unfortunate limitation when creating fluent APIs. To overcome this limitation you either need to:

1. Implement all the *API states* manually by, for example, an interface. This can be a feasible solution if your code is unlikely to change, e.g. in a project with rather limited scope that is not supposed to live for too long. A single backing class can then implement all the interfaces that represent each *API state*. As long as users do not use reflection or type castings, the compiler validates that methods are invoked in a legal order.
2. Auto-generate the code. This is a more ambitious approach but it can save you a lot of typing and refactoring effort if your *API state*-combinations "explode" as you say. I wrote a code generation library called [Byte Buddy](https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy) and I know of users using the library for creating interfaces for fluent APIs. (Unfortunately, the two users who I was in contact with on this matter did not open-source their code.) If you rather want to create Java source code instead of Java byte code then [Java poet](https://github.com/square/javapoet) might be an alternative for you which I have also seen for this use case.
3. Simplify your API to only validate the most common mistakes while checking for less common mistakes by exceptions at runtime. This often is a feasible solution as it makes the API more approachable.

Comment: Thank you very much already. Those two code generation projects seem fascinating. Writing all this code for code generation does not seem to be faster then just writing the interfaces/classes directly, however. I updated my question regarding the facade part.

Comment: Code generation can help you to automatically resolve all permutations of your fluent interface. For example, I could ask you to write a program that prints all permutations of the numbers 1-5. This would be a short program but writing down all numbers would take a lot of time. It is similar for your fluent interface. You can describe the code generator how to create all possible permutations without needing to write them down yourself. This is often less error prone (especially when refactoring) and quicker to implement.

Comment: Good point. It may help to find the answer to my question, but does not answer it yet (see edits). Nevertheless: Thanks a lot already.